# Linux: Removing terminated processes

Tags: linux, process, terminate

Why do these terminated python processes still take up memory?
I killed them with `kill` before.

How do I remove them without rebooting the system?

this is the output of `top`

```
top - 01:48:34 up  5:25,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.15, 0.73
Tasks: 282 total,   1 running, 238 sleeping,  43 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15483.1 total,   4861.2 free,   9689.3 used,    932.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   7971.0 total,   7462.0 free,    509.0 used.   5437.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
   8516 matthia+  20   0   89568   9604   8072 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.06 systemd                                                                                                                                 
   8523 matthia+  20   0  323044   2996     16 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 (sd-pam)                                                                                                                                
   8538 matthia+  20   0  507976   8184   6972 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.02 pulseaudio                                                                                                                              
   8588 matthia+  20   0   76484   5756   5220 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                             
   8590 matthia+  20   0  522672  10796   7672 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 gvfsd                                                                                                                                   
   8595 matthia+  20   0  379792   8264   7140 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.00 gvfsd-fuse                                                                                                                              
   8852 matthia+  20   0  163784   5260   4080 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.37 sshd                                                                                                                                    
   8855 matthia+  20   0  235756   4616   3256 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.14 bash                                                                                                                                    
   9640 matthia+  20   0  726992  52484  36644 T   0.0   0.3   0:00.18 python                                                                                                                                  
   9661 matthia+  20   0  953636 254480  19736 T   0.0   1.6   1:27.65 python                                                                                                                                  
   9662 matthia+  20   0  953736 225512  19272 T   0.0   1.4   1:27.68 python                                                                                                                                  
   9663 matthia+  20   0  953768 251920  19736 T   0.0   1.6   1:27.68 python                                                                                                                                  
   9664 matthia+  20   0  953744 236568  19736 T   0.0   1.5   1:27.67 python                                                                                                                                  
   9665 matthia+  20   0  953644 217700  19356 T   0.0   1.4   1:27.66 python                                                                                                                                  
   9666 matthia+  20   0  953600 246592  19736 T   0.0   1.6   1:27.65 python                                                                                                                                  
   9693 matthia+  20   0  726992 274520  36152 T   0.0   1.7   0:00.21 python                                                                                                                                  
   9714 matthia+  20   0  953636 476396  19532 T   0.0   3.0   0:03.29 python                                                                                                                                  
   9715 matthia+  20   0  953736 476328  19436 T   0.0   3.0   0:03.29 python                                                                                                                                  
   9716 matthia+  20   0  953768 476228  19724 T   0.0   3.0   0:03.30 python                                                                                                                                  
   9717 matthia+  20   0  953744 475772  19172 T   0.0   3.0   0:03.29 python                                                                                                                                  
   9718 matthia+  20   0  953644 475728  19252 T   0.0   3.0   0:03.30 python                                                                                                                                  
   9719 matthia+  20   0  953600 476048  19464 T   0.0   3.0   0:03.29 python                                                                                                                                  
   9733 matthia+  20   0  726992 277788  36444 T   0.0   1.8   0:00.21 python                                                                                                                                  
   9754 matthia+  20   0  953624 479008  19684 T   0.0   3.0   2:03.45 python                                                                                                                                  
   9755 matthia+  20   0  953744 479060  19664 T   0.0   3.0   2:03.44 python                                                                                                                                  
   9756 matthia+  20   0  953780 479232  19688 T   0.0   3.0   2:03.39 python                                                                                                                                  
   9757 matthia+  20   0  953744 478560  19464 T   0.0   3.0   2:03.43 python                                                                                                                                  
   9758 matthia+  20   0  953628 478732  19448 T   0.0   3.0   2:03.41 python                                                                                                                                  
   9759 matthia+  20   0  953600 478672  19612 T   0.0   3.0   2:03.42 python                                                                                                                                  
   9793 matthia+  20   0  726992 278024  36296 T   0.0   1.8   0:00.21 python                                                                                                                                  
   9814 matthia+  20   0  953624 471732  19568 T   0.0   3.0   0:10.65 python                                                                                                                                  
   9815 matthia+  20   0  953744 476700  19568 T   0.0   3.0   0:10.67 python                                                                                                                                  
   9816 matthia+  20   0  953780 473304  19568 T   0.0   3.0   0:10.68 python                                                                                                                                  
   9817 matthia+  20   0  953744 478216  19404 T   0.0   3.0   0:10.65 python                                                                                                                                  
   9818 matthia+  20   0  953628 477136  19408 T   0.0   3.0   0:10.65 python                                                                                                                                  
   9819 matthia+  20   0  953600 476736  19568 T   0.0   3.0   0:10.66 python                                                                                                                                  
   9861 matthia+  20   0  726856 282796  37132 T   0.0   1.8   0:00.21 python                                                                                                                                  
   9882 matthia+  20   0  954020 485460  20132 T   0.0   3.1   0:15.55 python                                                                                                                                  
   9883 matthia+  20   0  953972 485428  20000 T   0.0   3.1   0:15.51 python                                                                                                                                  
   9884 matthia+  20   0  953636 485464  20128 T   0.0   3.1   0:15.61 python                                                                                                                                  
   9885 matthia+  20   0  953612 485100  20028 T   0.0   3.1   0:15.59 python                                                                                                                                  
   9886 matthia+  20   0  953492 484860  19952 T   0.0   3.1   0:15.59 python                                                                                                                                  
   9887 matthia+  20   0  953500 484960  20068 T   0.0   3.1   0:15.54 python                                                                                                                                  
   9897 matthia+  20   0  726868 288000  36904 T   0.0   1.8   0:00.19 python                                                                                                                                  
   9898 matthia+  20   0  217080    948    872 T   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tee                                                                                                                                     
   9922 matthia+  20   0  954020 490580  19516 T   0.0   3.1   0:06.89 python                                                                                                                                  
   9923 matthia+  20   0  953608 490400  19744 T   0.0   3.1   0:06.86 python                                                                                                                                  
   9924 matthia+  20   0  953568 490224  19564 T   0.0   3.1   0:06.83 python                                                                                                                                  
   9925 matthia+  20   0  953612 490228  19564 T   0.0   3.1   0:06.89 python                                                                                                                                  
   9926 matthia+  20   0  953492 490096  19552 T   0.0   3.1   0:06.90 python                                                                                                                                  
   9927 matthia+  20   0  953500 490296  19744 T   0.0   3.1   0:06.88 python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State `T` is not terminated, it is "stopped by job control signal" ([man top](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)).

To get the processes into this state, you probably sent `SIGSTOP` to them (`kill -STOP ...`).  Instead, you should have sent a `SIGTERM` (the default), and you can still do that now.  If that doesn't work then send a `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Thanks, `killall python -s SIGKILL` removes them. However I did originally kill them using the standard `killall python`. I suppose that sends `SIGSTOP` by default then, in order to keep them in the job list?

Comment: Perhaps also ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Matthias, `SIGTERM` is the default for both `kill` and `killall`, which leaves it unclear how you ended up with the processes in the state they were in. But `SIGTERM` can be caught and handled (unlike `SIGKILL`), so it's possible that they caught the `SIGTERM`s and handled them by suspending themselves instead of terminating.

Comment: Interesting, I assume it depends then on what exact process is `kill`ed. I don't know the details about how python processes and subprocesses handle `SIGTERM`, but I guess this is what happened

Comment: Yes, @Matthias, the default behavior for a process that receives a `SIGTERM` is to terminate (abruptly).  If a process that receives a `SIGTERM` does not terminate then it is because that process has a handler for that signal installed that does something different.  This is why I initially speculated that you had sent a different signal.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger for clearing this up!